# How to remotely configure an enterprise Android app via an Enterprise Mobility Management tool?

Tags: android, configuration, android-management-api

I work for a business that provides an Android app to multiple clients.

Each client uses their own EMM (Enterprise Mobility Management) solution.

I am attempting to ascertain what the options are for remotely configuring our app on Android devices using EMMs.

The configuration I need to deliver is an 820 character string containing a license key.

Not every device will require this license key, so will need to be set on a per device level.

The current method we use to deliver configuration to our app is to transfer a file to the device containing the configuration details.

This method works OK except: it’s a bit primitive; and one of our client's EMMs does not provide this functionality.

I understand that Google provides Google Managed Account and Managed Google Play Accounts API’s that can be used to configure devices.

We have ruled out Google Managed Account as an option because it requires the client to sign up to G-Suite which carries quite a heavy financial cost, and would be overkill just for being able to deliver a license key.

Managed Google Play Accounts could possibly be an option. It appears to require a one off cost of applying for a developer license of only £20, which is fine. Once the app is uploaded to the client’s private Google Play Store it looks as though it  can be managed via the clients EMM UI, as long as it has the correct information in AndroidManifest.xml ( https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations ).

The Managed Google Play Account option could, potentially be the least worst option, but again having to introduce a dependency on Google services for a license key feels a but over the top, just not as over the top as using G-Suite.

Is there any other way, apart from the three methods mentioned above, of delivering app configuration to Android devices?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding managing multiple enterprises could be managed using https://developers.google.com/android/management/managed-configurations-iframe

Admin would have permission to manage multiple configuration files and devices on the console. We can also provision a device from the following strategy mentioned here https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device

You may also refer this link: https://developers.google.com/android/management/existing-emms for managing existing EMM's.